# /tmp always gets full even after resize

Tags: linux, centos5, tmp

I have a cPanel Server with 4GB of Ram and 4GB of /tmp space. I always get this error:

**Will this cause slow performance?** and can I delete everything?

```
Drive Critical: /tmp (/var/tmp) is 95% full

Drive Critical: /usr/tmpDSK (/tmp) is 95% full
```

Comment: could you post the output of "" cd /tmp && du -m|sort -nr|head "" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you definitely can't delete everything in there. /tmp is where the system stores its temporary files when it's running.

What you can delete depends on what's running on the server.

I would recommend looking at the file list and finding out what's writing so much to your /tmp folder. `ls -l` and `lsof` will be helpful in that respect.

The `ls -l` command gives you a detailed list of the files contained in the directory, and `lsof` will tell you which files that the processes on your server have open.

If these items exceed your technical skillset, I'd recommend contacting your reseller account's technical support or contracting someone who can assist you further.

Comment: Thanks, and will this cause performance issues ?

Comment: Thanks, I mean does full /tmp has impact on performance?

Comment: Yes, in that it certainly impacts the stability of your system's services if it can't create files there. It's not going to perform very well if your services' processes hang due to I/O blocking because they can't write to or create required files.